# Как сделать адаптивный баннер на всю высоту экрана с эффектом fullpage-скроллинга

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage

Подскажите библиотеки на JQuery, с помощью которых можно сделать эффект, как на баннере этого сайта? [пример](http://www.mariadelaguardia.com)

Т.е адаптивный баннер на весь экран, с центровкой дочернего diva и с эффектом fullpage-скроллинга.
Этот эффект нужен только для первой секции. У остальных будет обычный скроллинг.

Comment: сайт сделан на вот этой cms : https://craftcms.com/  где скорее всего это делается автоматом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, сама и решила свою проблему с помощью Alton+Hero Scroll.
Статья: https://paper-leaf.com/alton-jquery-scroll-jacking-plugin/
Демо: http://demo.paper-leaf.com/alton/heroscroll/